# Insert data into related tables with entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have two related tables ProcessBatches and Transfers [image]

First, I have to insert a record into `ProcessBatches`, then into `Transfers`.
I'm using the following code:

```
transferData.ProcessBatch = Context.ProcessBatches.Add(processBatchData);
Context.Transfers.Add(transferData);
Context.SaveChanges();
```

My question: Could it happen that in the worst case a record is inserted in `ProcessBatches` but not in `Transfers`?

Another idea that I had: First, insert the record in `ProcessBatches` then ask for the id and finally insert in `Transfers` (if the id is generated correctly)

Note: the id of both tables are generated automatically.

Comment: `SaveChanges` executes all modifications within single database transaction, so what you are asking could **not** happen.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do this instead:

```
transferData.ProcessBatch = processBatchData;
Context.Transfers.Add(transferData);
Context.ProcessBatches.Add(processBatchData);
Context.SaveChanges();
```

I believe that Add is a Void method, so it won't return anything. In your code, you are basically setting transferData.ProcessBatch to null.

Comment: The add method returns an entity